# Laravel Storage Linking is not working using symlinks command

Tags: php, laravel

I have uploaded my Laravel Web application to my server and tried to run the symlinks command but the media/images are not syncing. Anyone here can help me how to fix the storage issue?
here is my symlinks command :

```
<?php symlink('/home/webcxsol/shog/storage/app/public','/home/webcxsol/public_html/storage'); ?>
```

My public folder is in the public_html folder of the server and all the other files are in the other folder.

Comment: Where is your media/images folder located?

Comment: It is located inside the public folder. Public/Storage/profile_images.

Comment: The images are going to main storage folder but that storage folder is not getting synced with the storage folder which is inside the Public folder.

Comment: Everything looks ok... Did you delete the symlink file after running it?

Comment: I have deleted the storage folder inside the public folder and then hit the symlinks command again and now everything is working and images are getting synced too.I don't know how it get fixed

Comment: I am guessing you had a previous storage folder inside public folder before running symlink...

Answer (score 0):

If you are or wish to follow the framework conventions, there is a [specific command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk) for this which you could take a look at using: `php artisan storage:link`.